# How to call function before render in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, redux-saga, react-boilerplate

I am trying to send get method before component render to get data in state. I am using reducer, like this:

```
function mainPageReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case FETCH_PRODUCTS_BEGIN:
      return state
        .set('loading', true)
        .set('error', false)
        .setIn('products', false);
    case FETCH_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS:
      return state
        .setIn('products', action.products)
        .set('loading', false)
    case FETCH_PRODUCTS_FAILURE:
      return state.set('error', action.error).set('loading', false);
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Reducer gets the states and everything there looks working, but when I enter the page with this component it manage to reach `FETCH_PRODUCTS_BEGIN` state and only after render, it reaches `FETCH_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS`. So my list component doesn't get data of `action.products`.

In my component I tried to use both `componentDidMount` and `componentWillMount`, but results were the same.

My goal is to load component with list instantly, when page is loaded. Maybe someone could advise me how to achieve this?

**Edit:**

I have ProductsList component, where I check states. Component reaches loading state and after render he goes to null, which means that all states are false.

```
function ProductsList({ loading, error, products }) {
      if (loading) {
        return <List component={LoadingIndicator} />;
      }

      if (error !== false) {
        const ErrorComponent = () => (
          <ListItem item="Something went wrong, please try again!" />
        );
        return <List component={ErrorComponent} />;
      }

      if (products !==false) {
        return <List items={products} component={Products} />;
      }
      return null;
    }
```

Comment: are you dispatching the FETCH_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS action on success call back ?

Comment: @Srinivas, where should I do that? I am dispatching FETCH_PRODUCTS_BEGIN when component is about to render

Comment: @PrEto if you want to land on the page with the results, you may have to look at server side rendering of data.

Comment: @semuzaboi, could you show me example? It is exactly what I want

Comment: @PrEto .. ah! that is slightly beyond the scope of a single answer... since you are using sagas, i'd recommend going through some articles or repos like https://github.com/MartinCerny-awin/isomorphic-react-redux-saga-ssr

Comment: @semuzaboi, maybe there is possibility to rerender component in client side or is it a bad idea?

Comment: no it is absolutely not a bad idea... you can very well do it. Which is see you are already doing in your ProductList.  But , since you are saying it returns null , kindly console your props and check

Comment: @semuzaboi, thank you I just found that my selector was expecting not an array.

Answer (score 0):

you need to dispatch success call back action some thing like this:

```
function* login(action) {
  try {
    ....
    yield put({type: ACTION_TYPES.LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload:response.data});
  } catch (error) {
    yield put({type: ACTION_TYPES.LOGIN_FAILURE, error});
    yield call(alertError); // and this
  }
}
```

Reducer:

```
case GET_PROFILE_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        profile: action.payload,
        loading: false
      };
```

Comment: I am using redux-saga, so I am doing it like: `yield put(fetchProductsSuccess(products))`. It does dispatch effect as it says in: [Dispatching actions to the store](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/basics/DispatchingActions.html)

Comment: i have modified it according to redux-saga, pls check

Comment: there is no errors, I get arrays, but it happens after render

Answer (score 0):

In the saga:

```
yield put(FETCH_PRODUCTS_BEGIN);
yield take(FETCH_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS);
yield put(push(routes.productPage));
```